# Cakefile - how to --watch handlebars dir the same as coffeescript dir

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js, cakefile

When I --watch a directory containing coffeescript files, everything is caught- new files, immediate changes, but when I watch a handlebars directory it doesn't watch it. Am I right in thinking --watch is only available to coffee?

My Cakefile looks something like this:

```
{spawn} = require "child_process"
fs = require "fs"
handlebars = require "handlebars"

task 'watch', -> 
  spawn 'coffee', ['-cwj', 'js/libs/app.js', 'src/coffee']
  spawn 'handlebars', ['-wf', 'js/libs/templates.js', 'tmpl']
```

How can I watch a custom directory using a Cakefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `--watch` doesn't seem to be implemented by handlebars. You can use node's [`fs.watch`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) to hack up your own watcher. [Here's](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/command.html#section-14) how Coffeescript uses it to implement its own `watch` functionality.

Personally, I like using [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) for watching files, even if I'm working on a non-Ruby project. It's easier to set up than `fs.watch`.